# Error: descriptor 'strftime' for 'datetime.date' objects doesn't apply to a 'str' object

Tags: python, datetime

I bumped into error message in subject. I extracted the code into bare minimum and I have to admit I'm completely puzzled on what is going on here. Python code looks like this:

```
from datetime import datetime

time_string = '2022-08-23 08:48:02'
time_time = datetime.strptime(time_string, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
print(type(time_time)) # outputs <class 'datetime.datetime'>
time_string_again= datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d",time_time) # throws error in question subject
print(time_string_again)
```

Could you please explain to me what is wrong with above code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using strftime in the wrong way. You can check the right usage here: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strftime

basically, strftime is applied to your datetime object:

```
time_string_again = time_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

Comment: OMG, I'm bit ashamed here. Thanks!!